# Error in build project with opencv

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I want to build [YOLO](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/) in ubuntu 16.04 with opencv. I install opencv with

> sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev

However when I run `make` I get

> ./src/image.c:509:29: error: unknown type name 'CvCapture'
>
> image get_image_from_stream(**C**vCapture *cap)

Note that I can successfully build without opencv.(Sorry for my poor English).

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You'd better refer to this [link](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/pull/38). Add the following header file inside `#ifdef OPENCV` blocks of those files.

```
#include "opencv2/videoio/videoio_c.h"
```